# @ManyToOne with native query leads to N+1 select

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I know the problem with N+1 select is well-known, but trying using different fetching strategies does not help to avoid it when I use native query.

I have 2 entities: A and B that correspond to the mysql tables A and B.
Several rows in table A could have the same b_id, that's why I use @ManyToOne annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private B b;
}
```

I also create entity B.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  private String url;
}
```

I need to find all rows in A that are linked only for 1 row in table B. So I create native query in my ARepository

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer> {
 @Query(value = "SELECT a.id, a.b_id, a.name, b.url "
          + "FROM a "
          + "JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id "
          + "GROUP BY a.b_id "
          + "HAVING count(a.b_id) = 1, nativeQuery = true)
  List<A> getLinkedOnce();
```

But when when I run my restcontroller that just call getLinkedOnce method from repository, I see that in console, 1-st my query is called, then there are number of selects for each row in A that are end with

```
from B b0_ where b0_.id=?
```

I try to use different approaches, LAZY, EAGER and it does not work. I think because there is a usage of native query. But maybe the reason is another.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the @ManyToOne annotation completely? Make it so that the only query containing "JOIN" that runs is your native query.

Comment: This JPA query looks a bit odd - it seems this is no valid JPA query. "b_id" does not exist in the entity, group by has to use all columns, etc.

Comment: ` a.b_id = b.id` ? Where is `b_id` ? You dont use ids if using mapped entities. `a.b.id` is a more appropriate. Joins are done differently in JPA (they are ommited ususally).

Comment: @Antoniossss, could you give how it could be rewrited? I mean entity and repository?